# Error: Error: [ethjs-rpc] rpc error with payload {"id":6223335088050,"jsonrpc":"2.0","params":

Tags: solidity, remix, metamask, testrpc, myetherwallet

I have deployed a smart contract in Remix IDE using MetaMask and test rpc. I got the below error:

```
Error: Error: [ethjs-rpc] rpc error with payload {"id":6223335088050,"jsonrpc":"2.0","params":["0xf9061.......f2b"],"method":"eth_sendRawTransaction"} Error: transaction underpriced
```

So, please give me solution to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

[ethjs-rpc] rpc error with payload 
in Solidity 0.5.0 happens if the passed parameters to the contract is empty, hence from DApp console log all parameters and see if any values are being passed as empty or null. Once you address the empty values to some concrete values rpc error will go way and transaction will be success.

Answer (score 2):

I have come across the same error. After removing and re-installing the meta mask has been fixed this problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

I kept getting this error some time before when metamask by default set gas price to 0. Took some time to notice it, but changing it from 0 to anything else fixed the problem.

Comment: how did you changed it

Comment: Before sending tx you can set gas limit in MetaMask.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Remix+Metamask, when deploying on the main-net, the white window will popup with remix. Make sure the number for GAS matches what you are going to insert into Metamask. For example, if the number is 53 and you set it very low with metamask (to lets say 13), you will get the error... so instead of 53, you have to enter 13...